# C# FIFO Queue Like BLockingCollection without waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I want to have a FIFO Queue with the following requirements:

- If queue is empty, wait for one element to be added
- Start processing as soon as one element is in the Q
- If elements pending in the Q are more than X, drop them.

I used a `BlockingCollection` like this:

```
public LoggerReal() 
{
    main = (frmMain)Application.OpenForms[0];
    LogQueue = new BlockingCollection<logEntry>(GlobalSettings.LogQueueSize);
    Task.Run(() => {
        foreach (logEntry LE in LogQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {    
            try {
                ProcessLogEntry(LE);
            } catch (Exception E) {
                functions.Logger.log("Error processing logEntry" + E.Message, "LOGPROCESSING", LOGLEVEL.ERROR);
                functions.printException(E);
            }

        }
        functions.Logger.log("Exiting Queue Task", "LOGPROCESSING", LOGLEVEL.ERROR);
    });
}
```

However, I noticed that the logs seems to show only when the queue was full.
`ProcessLogEntry` function simply puts them into a `ListBox`.

I tried using simple queue with no luck.

As far as I could tell, ConcurrentQueue and other Queue might not fulfill these requirements, or am I wrong? I start the Queue processor into a Task so it can be waiting forever, that is not an issue, but it needs to start processing as soon as data is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your requirements, you can use a regular `Queue<T>` with simple `Monitor` based signaling like this:

**Members:**

```
private readonly int maxSize;
private readonly Queue<logEntry> logQueue;
private bool stopRequest;
```

Constructor:

```
maxSize = GlobalSettings.LogQueueSize;
logQueue = new Queue<logEntry>(maxSize);
```

**Producer method:**

```
public void Add(logEntry logEntry)
{
    lock (logQueue)
    {
        if (stopRequest) return;
        logQueue.Enqueue(logEntry);
        if (logQueue.Count == 1)
            Monitor.Pulse(logQueue);
    }
}
```

**Method to stop the process worker:**

```
public void Stop()
{
    lock (logQueue)
    {
        if (stopRequest) return;
        stopRequest = true;
        Monitor.Pulse(logQueue);
    }
}
```

**Process worker (the method called with `Task.Run`):**

```
private void ProcessWorker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        logEntry LE;
        lock (logQueue)
        {
            while (!stopRequest && logQueue.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait(logQueue);
            if (stopRequest) break;
            if (logQueue.Count > maxSize)
            {
                logQueue.Clear();
                continue;
            }
            LE = logQueue.Dequeue();
        }
        try
        {
            ProcessLogEntry(LE);
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            functions.Logger.log("Error processing logEntry" + E.Message, "LOGPROCESSING", LOGLEVEL.ERROR);
            functions.printException(E);
        }
    }
    functions.Logger.log("Exiting Queue Task", "LOGPROCESSING", LOGLEVEL.ERROR);
}
```

This is just to get the idea, you can further tune the implementation to better suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that !

Answer (score 0):

Your title is somewhat confusing (FIFO is a queue, and a blocking collection waits/blocks by definition?).  However, I'm going to guess at what you want here...

I'm going to assume you want 2 threads, one which is adding to the queue (writer), and the other which is blocked/waiting to process items as soon as they're added (reader).

Create a blocking collection:

```
var dataSink = new BlockingCollection<logEntry]>(new ConcurrentQueue<logEntry>());
```

The 'writer' thread simply adds and continues on it's way

```
dataSink.Add(logEntryToAdd);  // Add to collection and continue
```

The 'reader' thread blocks until an item is added to the queue

```
while (dataSink.Count > 0)
{
    ProcessLogEntry(dataSink.Take());
}
```

I'm not sure about your overflow "X" but perhaps during the 'add' operation you can get the count and if it exceeds 'x' either don't add or dequeue the first item (depends on what your logic flow entails).

Obviously, be sure that the UI thread is NOT blocked (UI thread should not be the 'reader', create a 3rd thread if needed which blocks/reads from the queue and then notifies the UI via an invoke to update the Listbox) otherwise your UI will become unresponsive...

Comment: The problem is that my Queue Count might reach 0 (so dataSink.Count > 0 would be false) at some point, but further data will be added later... This class handles log event. So while some actions might generate a flood of log event, sometime there might be none... I want to ensure that they will be processed sequentially, with a maximum of entry in the processing queue

Comment: btw, the "while" loop can also be while(true) to continuously block/read from the queue.  I'd advice you to have a way to break out of the loop when you're ready to close everything down though (eg pass a cancellation token to the .Take() call so you can abort the block and exit the loop).

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, I used BlockingCollection, but I do a while loop with tryTake instead of using the ConsumingEnumerable:

```
  Task.Run(() => {
            while (!LogQueue.IsCompleted) {

                logEntry LE;
                LogQueue.TryTake(out LE, Timeout.Infinite);

                try {
                    ProcessLogEntry(LE);
                } finally {
                   // Do nothing, because if logging cause issue, logging exception is likely to do so as well...
                }
            }
            //functions.Logger.log("Exiting Queue Task", "LOGPROCESSING", LOGLEVEL.ERROR); // Will not work if exiting Q
        });
```